# Por qué el formulario hace submit al presionar Enter en algunos casos?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony2

Tengo el siguiente código que básicamente muestra una ventana modal y en la misma se carga un fragmento de vista correspondiente a un formulario básandose en el atributo `href` del elemento al que se le asocia el evento `click`. En diferentes vistas de la aplicación hago uso de la función, y esta sucediendo que en algunas de ellas al presionar Enter se está haciendo el submit del formulario y en otras nop, el comportamiento deseado debería ser que no se realice el submit, de hecho el botón es un `input` de tipo `button` y no de tipo `submit`.

```
$('#vistas').on('click', '#lnkNuevoRegistro', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elemento = $(this);
        var titulo = elemento.attr('title');
        var cerrarDialogo = elemento.attr('data-cerrar-dialogo');
        $(document.body).find('#modalCaptura').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: elemento.attr('href'),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').fadeIn('fast');
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $(document.body).append("<div id='modalCaptura' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1'  role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Cerrar'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h5 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'></h5></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenedorForm' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button><button id='btnSalvar' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Salvar</button></div></div></div></div>");
            if (titulo === undefined) {
                $(".modal-title").html("<strong>Nuevo registro</strong>");
            } else {
                $(".modal-title").html('<strong>' + titulo + '</strong>');
            }
            $("#contenedorForm").html(data);
            $('#modalCaptura').modal({
                keyboard: false,
                backdrop: 'static'
            }).on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var dialogo = $(this);
                $("#btnSalvar").on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var btn = $(this);
                    if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: $("#modalCaptura").find("form").attr('action'),
                            data: $("#modalCaptura").find("form").serialize(),
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                btn.addClass('disabled');
                                $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').fadeIn('fast');
                            }
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            if (cerrarDialogo === "1") {
                                $(dialogo).modal('hide');
                                $('#indicador').html(data);
                            } else {
                                $(dialogo).find('#contenedorForm').html(data);
                            }
                            $('#vistas').find('#lnkRecargaRegistros').trigger('click');
                        }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
                            if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                            } else if (jqXHR.status === 406) {
                                $(document.body).find("div[class='datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu']").remove();
                                $(dialogo).find('#contenedorForm').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                            } else {
                                $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
                        }).always(function(status) {
                            btn.removeClass('disabled');
                            if (cerrarDialogo === "1") {
                                if (status !== 'success') {
                                    $('#indicador').fadeOut(5500, function() {
                                        $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    $('#indicador').fadeOut(4000, function() {
                                        $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(document.body).find("div[class='datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu']").remove();
                $(document.body).find('#modalCaptura').remove();

            });
        }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
            } else {
                $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }).always(function(status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                $('#indicador').fadeOut(5500, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                });
            } else {
                $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Este un fragmento de vista `twig` que si se fijan no tiene nada del otro mundo, como ese tengo varios en diferentes modulos, con algunos se hace el submit, con otros nop. Incluso, cuando cargo fragmentos de vista muchos más personalizados los campos (o más bien las grillas donde se muestran los widgets), tampoco sucede el submit.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        {{ form_start(form) }}        
        {{ form_errors(form) }}        
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Este el es resultado html del fragmento de vista anterior:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <form name="consejo_popular" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/registrar-nuevo-consejo-popular/19" class="form-horizontal">        

        <div id="consejo_popular">    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label required" for="consejo_popular_nombre">Nombre</label><div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="consejo_popular_nombre" name="consejo_popular[nombre]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="form-control"></div>
</div><input type="hidden" id="consejo_popular__token" name="consejo_popular[_token]" value="4S-avYTM6GHSTV6xuK80zVZT7fepNL2cEm75W50wix8"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anh, el submit al presionar Enter se realiza cuando el formulario tiene el campo con valor, vacío no lo hace.

************* Editando ***************

He cambiado el evento click del botón por el submit del formulario, y el propio botón por un input de tipo submit, ahora en algunos formularios al presionar Enter si los campos están llenos, se realiza el submit pero se pierde el evento click del botón (o input de tipo submit). En resumen deseo mantener el evento click para ejecutar el envío del formulario, pero que al presionar enter no se realice el submit como está sucediendo en algunos casos; se efectúa el submit como petición tradicional y el controlador está programado para responder solo a peticiones vía AJAX.
He estado pensando en programar el evento submit del formulario de manera tal que prevenga el comportamiento por defecto y no se responda al mismo, no se si tenga efecto, probaré:

```
$('#contenedorForm form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

El formulario, aunque tu botón no sea de tipo submit, implícitamente siempre va a tener un submit, que se ejecuta cuando pulsas "ENTER" en algún input, lo mejor que puedes hacer es que en vez de hacer tu función en el .click del botón lo hagas en el .submit del formulario, de esta manera evitas que el formulario se envíe de forma errónea cuando se pulsa enter.

cambia esta linea de código

```
$('#vistas').on('click', '#lnkNuevoRegistro', function(e) {
```

Por este

```
$('#idDelForm').submit(function(e) {
```

Donde id del form se lo tienes que agregar a tu formulario, puede ser el mismo que el name y cambiar el tipo de tu botón por submit, esto incluso te ayuda por que al pulsar el botón te valida los campos "required" del formulario con la ayuda de HTML5 y le agregas una capa más de seguridad a tu formulario.

Si se te dificulta escribe de nuevo para ayudarte

Comment: En todo caso sería sustituir  $("#btnSalvar").on('click', function(e){}); por el evento submit del formulario, deja probar.

Comment: Asi es, espero te funcione, es la mejor práctica cuando a formularios se refiere